# How to get values from a table field and insert it into another table with a foreach statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help. I need to create query that checks if entries exist in the table 'tblLocalization' for the selected fields mentioned in the parameters. if the entries exist then it updates the values. If it does not exist then it will insert the values fields ( "pk" and "fieldName") into that database.

public void Extract(string dbName, string tableName, string fieldName)

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
//check if entry already exists in tblLocalization for that dbName, tableName, fieldName, PK(s)

//if exists, create update SQL statement to update the language field in tblLocalization with the fieldName value

//if doesn’t exist, create insert SQL statement to add the row in tblLocalization with the dbName, tableName, fieldName, PK(s) and language field values

```
 string checkQuery = @"SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblLocalization where tField = " +fieldName+ " AND val_en_US = " + row[fieldName] + "AND PKVal1 = " +row[pk]+ ") then UPDATE tblLocalization SET " + selectLang +"= " + row[fieldName] +" ELSE INSERT into tblLocalization " + "(tDatabase, tTable, tField, PKVal1, val_en_US)" +   " VALUES ("+dbName+", "+tableName+", "+fieldName+", "+row[pk]+ ", " +row[fieldName]+")";

                    //execute the SQL

                    dataStoreLocalizer.ExecuteNonQuery(checkQuery);
                }
```

Comment: Please read http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Take a look at a MERGE statement

Comment: You are looking for an upsert statement, insert update combined. 
There are so many guide out there on how to do that, I encourage you to just google "upsert C# SQL"